# How to redirect all server aliases and www to SSL non www in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost, http-redirect

Looking for a way to redirect several server aliases (both www and non-www) to one non-www domain with forced SSL using Apache VirtualHosts and `.htaccess`. I've been searching for a while now and have found several solutions but they all work partially.

The situation is as follows, in my `.conf` file I have a virtual host specified as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example.domain
        ServerAlias *.example.domain *.exampledomain.com exampledomain.com

        ...

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example.domain
        ServerAlias *. example.domain *.exampledomain.com exampledomain.com

        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.domain [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.domain
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Next, I have the following in my `.htaccess`:

```
        RewriteEngine On
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exampledomain.com$ [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampledomain.com$ [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.domain$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.domain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Result is as follows:

```
http://example.domain/          -> https://example.domain/ - (correct)
http://www.example.domain/      -> https://example.domain/ - (correct)

http://exampledomain.com/       -> http://exampledomain.com/ - Forbidden, you dont have access...
http://www.exampledomain.com/   -> http://www.exampledomain.com/ - Forbidden, you dont have access...

https://exampledomain.com/      -> https://example.domain/ - (correct)
https://www.exampledomain.com/  -> https://www.exampledomain.com/ - Connection not secure
```

I really can't figure out where this goes wrong and why some redirects work and others don't. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the `<VirtualHost>` then you don't need to (should not) use `.htaccess` at all for this.

If the goal is to redirect to the canonical domain (+HTTPS) in a single redirect using just the two vHosts as defined then all you need is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.domain
    ServerAlias *.example.domain *.exampledomain.com exampledomain.com

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect everything other than the canonical host to the canonical host
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example\.domain
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.domain%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.domain
    ServerAlias *.example.domain *.exampledomain.com exampledomain.com

    # Unconditionally redirect everything to HTTPS + canonical host
    Redirect 301 / https://example.domain/
</VirtualHost>
```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix matching and everything after the match is appended to the end of the target URL. So, the `Redirect` directive above redirects every URL to the same URL at the target.

You should test first with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to a 301 (permanent) once you have confirmed it works as intended. You will likely need to clear your browser cache since 301s are cached persistently by the browser.

---

**A look at your "results":**

```
http://exampledomain.com/       -> http://exampledomain.com/ - Forbidden, you dont have access...
http://www.exampledomain.com/   -> http://www.exampledomain.com/ - Forbidden, you dont have access...
```

The current HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the vHost:80 container is only redirecting `www.example.domain` and `example.domain` and you probably aren't accepting requests in the vHost:80 container, so any HTTP request (that is not redirected to HTTPS) is probably blocked.

```
https://www.exampledomain.com/  -> https://www.exampledomain.com/ - Connection not secure
```

Your SSL cert needs to cover all domains and all aliases, otherwise, you will (at best) get a browser SSL cert warning and the browser will refuse to connect to your server (so does not see the redirect).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for pointing me in the right direction and the minor text adjustments in my question.